# Where can I download backup files of Mainnet Blocks?

Tags: nodeos

I need all block data of eos mainnet. So, My nodeos is downloading now. However, it will take so many hours(maybe days?) and sometimes occurs errors.
while finding another method to get them, 
I found the site: https://eosnode.tools/blocks. But it only supplies block files for ubuntu OS. Can i download a backup files of eos mainnet blocks for mac?

Answer (score 1):

No, but did you try to adjust the config.ini ? Using bnet plugin, switching to light mode. I noticed when using mongodb, it takes way longer.

It might be a good idea to just rent a server from Digitalocean and download the already mentioned files. It's really easy and cheap. Notice that nodeos is single core, so choosing a stronger CPU is smarter than having 8 cores. 8GB Ram is minimum

Answer (score 1):

The blocks.log files are platform agnostic.  They can be used for a replay on any OS for which you can compile nodeos.

Answer (score 0):

Now(2020.08.08) you can get blocks.log from here https://archive.eoseoul.io/